# Help with Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit: focusing sidebar component tab from different tab in same component

Tags: visualforce, custom-console-components, consoleintegrationtoolkit

Does anyone have experience with the Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit, specifically the focusSidebarComponent() function.
I have a few different VF pages displayed in the sidebar (CustomerKb (id="CustKbVF" name="CustKbVF"), Announcements) and I want to set up a JS onclick to focus CustomerKb from the Announcements tab. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function focusCustKb() { 
    sforce.console.focusSidebarComponent(JSON.stringify({componentType:'VISUALFORCE',
                                                         pageName: 'CustKbVF'}), "CustKbVF", focusSuccess);
}
var focusSuccess = function focusSuccess(result) {
    //Report whether going to the tab was successful
    if (result.success == true) {
        alert('Going to the tab was successful');
    } else {
        alert('Going to the tab was not successful');
    } 

};
</script>

<A HREF="#" onClick="focusCustKb();return false">
    Click here to focus Customer Kb</A>
```

[image: Screenshot of Console]

[image: Screenshot of layout]

Comment: What behavior do you observe? Are you seeing any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: @AdrianLarson when I click on the link it stays on the same tab and pops up the announcement "Going to the tab was not successful". There is nothing in chrome's inspect element console when I click the button.

Comment: Done, sorry. New to Stack Exchange.

Comment: The component id is almost certainly not `CustKbVF`, that's likely your issue. I don't see how to get the correct value though. Hmm...

Comment: I tried using 
> var tabId = sforce.console.getFocusedSubtabId(result);
> sforce.console.focusSidebarComponent({componentType:'VISUALFORCE', pageName: 'CustKbVF'}, tabId.id, focusSuccess);
But I probably did that wrong.

Comment: It's an asynchronous method, so you would have to use it from a callback.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll work on that a bit more and post in here if I get it working. Thanks for looking at it with me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was up. I had incorrect values for the `pageName` and `tabId` fields.  `pageName` should have been the actual name of the visualforce page minus the extension (CustomConsoleCustomerKbTab) and not the `name=""` value.  The `tabId` should have been left blank `""`.  The console will assume it's the current tab if left blank. Works like a charm now!

```
function focusCustKb() 
{ sforce.console.focusSidebarComponent 
(JSON.stringify({componentType:'VISUALFORCE',
                 pageName: 'CustomConsoleCustomerKbTab'}), "", focusSuccess);}
```